# Why won't Visual Studio 2012 let me change fonts?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fonts

Every font I try to change to that isn't Consolas or Courier just shows up as Courier.

I don't understand. Terminal, FixedSys, Terminus (custom), Lucida Console, and every other mono-space font I tried using just comes up as Courier.

I've ran VS as Administrator, re-logged, changed my control panel font size settings, tried different zoom %'s within VS, change the font size around a bunch within VS as well... nothing seems to work.

I googled around and couldn't find anyone with the same problem. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "just comes up as Courier"?  Does the font name switch back or does the font stay named "Consolas" but actually is displaying "Courier"?

Comment: The font name is what I set it to - the font face however appears as Courier. Within the preview of the Fonts & Colors pane, the correct font appears. But my actual code is rendered as courier.

Comment: Same problem here, except just with a particular font.  It always falls back to Courier New.  Annoying.

Comment: I never found a solution to this - I did however stop experiencing this problem after upgrading to Visual Studio 2017.